# what where clause should I use to get objects greater than the creation date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

In my DB the objects are saved with creation date in the format, dd-month-year hours:seconds (example `2011-12-07 09:59:41`). What sql commands should I use to get objects created after April 2012?

Comment: `2011-12-07 09:59:41` is year-month-day hour:min:sec` :)

Comment: Your example does not match the format you provided.

Comment: Saved as strings in that format, or saved as date objects?

Comment: What is the data type of the `creation date` column?

Comment: With "after april", do you mean May?

Comment: "After April" means April 1st, including; April 1st, excluding; or May 1st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- After April 1st, including
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   creationDate >= CAST('2012-04-01' AS DATE)

-- After April 1st, excluding
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   creationDate >= '2012-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY

-- After April
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   creationDate >= '2012-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(creationDate, '%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

(you are asking after april 2012, which is may)

Comment: This will return lots of incorrect matches, including, for instance, `April 30th`. You are comparing strings here.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CreationDate > '2012-04-00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this link](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/sql-date-greater-than.shtml)

You want the bit at the bottom.

Example:

```
SELECT * from table where DATE >='2008-12-03';
```

Comment: Web pages have a bad habit of going off-line all of a sudden. Please consider extracting the bit you think the OP wants, and re-posting it here.